# Python throws exception reading JSON file into a class

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

I have the following JSON code which is read into my python file:

```
{
        "10":
    {
        "object": 10,
        "singles": [
            {
                "name": "Hello",
                "special_numbers": [1,2,5]
            },
            {
                "name": "World",
                "special_numbers": [1,10]
            }
        ],
        "doubles": []
    }
}
```

The file gets open by this:

```
objects_config = None

with open("file_objects.json", "r") as file:
    objects_config = json.load(file)
```

The reading of it occurs in another file, which causes the exception listed at the bottom here:

```
// the request.object is a string of 10
object_details = MyClass(**object_config[str(request.object)]["singles"])
```

This is the class the JSON will write into:

```
from typing import List

class MyClass(object):

    name = None
    special_numbers = None

    def __init__(self, name: str, special_numbers: List[int]):
        self.name = name
        self.special_numbers = special_numbers

    #debug
    def __repr__(self):
        return f'<MyClass(name={self.name})>'
```

The exception is this:

```
type object argument after ** must be a mapping, not list
```

Not quite sure what is going on as super new to python.

Comment: `object["singles"]` is a list, not a dictionary.  The ** syntax is used to pass a dictionary as keyword arguments.  Did you want the first item in the list?

Comment: And if `request.object` is already a string, then it is pointless to pass it to `str()`.

Comment: Cool thanks. I'm trying to learn python on the fly.

Comment: So what happens if I ignore the first line in the JSON? As in the "object": 10 part

Comment: `object_config = None` doesn't do anything useful. You can omit it.

Comment: The same goes for the unused class attributes `name` and `special_numbers`. The assignments inside `__init__` are all you need.

Answer (score 1):

`object_config["10"]["singles"]` results in a list of 2 dictionaries, not a single dictionary. For this you would have to construct 2 objects

```py
singles = object_config[str(request.object)]["singles"]

# Like this
object0_details = MyClass(**singles[0])
object1_details = MyClass(**singles[1])

# Or use a for loop
objects = []
for s in singles:
    objects.append(MyClass(**s))
```

Also you should look into dataclasses. It does what MyClass does but in better, cleaner code.

Btw this `class MyClass(object):` is equal to this `class MyClass`. From what I know `(object)` was needed for python 2 but is not anymore

Comment: Okay but now I get: Exception has occurred: TypeError       (note: full exception trace is shown but execution is paused at: process)
__init__() takes 3 positional arguments but 4 were given

Comment: Didn't test correctly at first and answered wrong. Updated and it should be correct now.